# Почему теряется часть данных при merge двух DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Коллеги, приветствую!Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при выполнении merge некоторые данные у меня затираются (NaN), в зависимости от how?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NaN` появляется при использовании "outer-joins" (`left`,`right`,`outer`) в случае когда в подчиненной таблице нет данных в "связном" столбце (`Person Responsible` в вашем случае). Т.е. `NaN` можно рассматривать как `NULL` в реляционных СУБД...

Пример:

Данные:

```
In [8]: a = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3], 'A':[11,12,13]})

In [9]: b = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[3,4], 'B':[200,300]})

In [10]: a
Out[10]:
    A  ID
0  11   1
1  12   2
2  13   3

In [11]: b
Out[11]:
     B  ID
0  200   3
1  300   4
```

`how='inner'` (SQL: inner join):

```
In [12]: a.merge(b, on=['ID'])
Out[12]:
    A  ID    B
0  13   3  200
```

`how='left'` (SQL: left outer join) - в выборке все записи из "левой таблицы - `a`" и только те из `правой`, у которых существует сооств. `ID`:

```
In [13]: a.merge(b, on=['ID'], how='left')
Out[13]:
    A  ID      B
0  11   1    NaN
1  12   2    NaN
2  13   3  200.0
```

`how='right'` (SQL: right outer join) - в выборке все записи из "правой таблицы - `b`" и только те из `левой`, у которых существует сооств. `ID`:

```
In [15]: a.merge(b, on=['ID'], how='right')
Out[15]:
      A  ID    B
0  13.0   3  200
1   NaN   4  300
```

`how='outer'` (SQL: full outer join) - в выборке все записи из обеих таблиц:

```
In [16]: a.merge(b, on=['ID'], how='outer')
Out[16]:
      A  ID      B
0  11.0   1    NaN
1  12.0   2    NaN
2  13.0   3  200.0
3   NaN   4  300.0
```

---

Но самое "интересное" начинается когда у вас в связном столбце(ах) появляются дупликаты - в результирующем наборе будут все комбинации из двух таблиц:

```
In [17]: a.loc[len(a)] = [14, 3]

In [18]: b.loc[len(b)] = [400, 3]

In [19]: a
Out[19]:
    A  ID
0  11   1
1  12   2
2  13   3  # duplicates for ID: 3
3  14   3  # duplicates for ID: 3

In [20]: b
Out[20]:
     B  ID
0  200   3  # duplicates for ID: 3
1  300   4
2  400   3  # duplicates for ID: 3
```

Inner join:

```
In [21]: a.merge(b, on=['ID'])
Out[21]:
    A  ID    B
0  13   3  200  # A: 13, B: 200
1  13   3  400  # A: 13, B: 400
2  14   3  200  # A: 14, B: 200
3  14   3  400  # A: 14, B: 400
```

Outer joins:

```
In [22]: a.merge(b, on=['ID'], how='left')
Out[22]:
    A  ID      B
0  11   1    NaN
1  12   2    NaN
2  13   3  200.0
3  13   3  400.0
4  14   3  200.0
5  14   3  400.0

In [23]: a.merge(b, on=['ID'], how='right')
Out[23]:
      A  ID    B
0  13.0   3  200
1  14.0   3  200
2  13.0   3  400
3  14.0   3  400
4   NaN   4  300

In [24]: a.merge(b, on=['ID'], how='outer')
Out[24]:
      A  ID      B
0  11.0   1    NaN
1  12.0   2    NaN
2  13.0   3  200.0
3  13.0   3  400.0
4  14.0   3  200.0
5  14.0   3  400.0
6   NaN   4  300.0
```

**UPDATE:**

> как выполнить преобразоване типов, например: `str` --> `int`?

я знаю два способа "векторизированного" преобразования `str` в `int`:

```
df_3['Person Responsible'] = pd.to_numeric(df_3['Person Responsible'], errors='coerce')
```

и

```
df_3['Person Responsible'] = df_3['Person Responsible'].astype(int, raise_on_error=False)
```

в первом случае те значения, которые не могут быть преобразованы в числа (например строка `'AAA'`) будут заменены на `NaN` и `dtype` у всего столбца будет `float64`, во втором случае будут преобразованы только те значения, которые возможно преобразовать и `dtype` у всего столбца будет либо `int` если **все** значения были успешно преобразованы, либо останется `object`

Преобразовать `int` --> `str` проще:

```
ft['Person Responsible'] = ft['Person Responsible'].astype(str)
```

Comment: MaxU, спасибо, но думаю дело не в этом. Там есть данные, которые по ключу совпадают. По моей задумке все данные которые не совпали по ключу Person Responsible будут отфильтрованы по NaN и я получу чистый фрейм с полностью заполненными сериями. Скажите, может быть дело в том, что перед этим я фрейм ft также создал из двух фпеймов методом merge?

Comment: Честно говоря пока не понимаю, что добавить к вышеизложенному, но пока не решил эту проблему. Отложу, до наступления озарения. Спасибо MaxU.

Comment: @DenisNovik, я бы посоветовал вам запостить в вопрос небольшие (по  3-5 строк), но __воспроизводимые__ данные (в текстовом виде, чтобы их можно было скопировать и использовать в коде) - например несколько совпадающих и несовпадающих `Person Responsible` и показать чего вы хотите добиться. Вообще `merge()` в Pandas достаточно прост (не считая случаев с дупликатами) - он работает точно также как в реляционных СУБД

Comment: MaxU, а подскажите, пожалуйста, может быть причина в dtype? Я смотрю в одном фрейме у меня Person Responsible имеет тип int64, в другом non-null object.

Comment: @DenisNovik, конечно! Pandas не будет неявно преобразовывать типы во время `merge`

Comment: если не трудно, можете подсказать как мне преобразоване выполнить? Я пробовал явно приводить и в одном фрейме и в другом таким образом: df_3['Person Responsible'] = int(df_3['Person Responsible']), но получаю ошибку "cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>". Пробовал через astype, но там я пока не очень понимаю описание, которое функция help дает

Comment: @DenisNovik, какой тип "более правильный" - `int` или `str` (`object`)? Т.е. к какому типу приводить?

Comment: так как это номер, то более правильный int, на мой взгляд.

Comment: @DenisNovik, смотрите UPDATE в ответе

Comment: спасибо! Работает, но не получается как нужно. Я update обновил.

Comment: @DenisNovik, `6.709053e+09` - показывает, что есть значения, которые не могут быть преобразованы в числа, поэтому все числа будут иметь dtype: `float64`. Соответственно вам надо преобразовать этот столбец в строку в `ft` DF- `ft['Person Responsible'] = ft['Person Responsible'].astype(str)`

Comment: @DenisNovik, похоже вы при создании `ft` что-то сделали не так...

Comment: еще раз большое вам человеческое спасибо за помощь! Проблему решил преобразовав Person Responsible из int -->str. Все прекрасно слилось. Теперь несусь на встречу следующим стакам)